# "Available soon" vs. "Soon available"

Tags: word-usage

As in a callout announcing a new product: "Available soon at your xyz dealer" or "Soon available at your xyz dealer!

Comment: Are you asking which one is preferable? (In my opinion they're basically interchangeable.)

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed my question. "Available soon" seems to win the popularity contest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the same thing, and both are grammatically fine. "Available soon" is much more commonly seen and used, so I'd go with that. "Soon available" has also seen some use, but it's [never been popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soon%20available&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoon%20available%3B%2Cc0) compared to ["available soon"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=available%20soon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavailable%20soon%3B%2Cc0).